# Запятая на стыке союзов, если соотносительное слово заменено на тире

Tags: пунктуация, союзы

Как известно, запятая на стыке союзов *не ставится*, если далее имеется коррелят:

> А я тебе говорю, чт**о е**сли ты поедешь, **то** я поеду с тобой.

Если коррелят (в данном случае частица *то*) отсутствует, запятая ставится:

> А я тебе говорю, чт**о, е**сли ты поедешь, я поеду с тобой.

А как быть в случае замены *то* на тире?

"На глаз" запятой не должно быть, поскольку тире вроде бы несёт функцию соотносительного слова:

> А я тебе говорю, чт**о е**сли ты поедешь — я поеду с тобой.

Но я не уверен, так ли это.

Comment: Вы правы, запятая здесь не нужна, так как СПП рассматривается как единое целое. Постановка запятой  сделает неясным понимание структуры предложения.

Comment: @Sharon а если две запятые, а тире рассматривать не как замену *то*, а как интонационное? Как полагаете, такая запись возможна? *А я тебе говорю, что, если ты поедешь, — я поеду с тобой*.

Comment: Я думаю, интонационное тире  может заменять запятую, а не добавляться к ней. А иначе это выглядит как единый знак (запятая и тире), а он здесь совсем ни к чему.  Да и первая запятая мешает пониманию грамматики предложения.  В этом варианте тире разделительное (голос перед паузой повышается), тогда ясно выражена взаимообусловленность двух предложений  (условие – событие). В БСП в таких случаях ставится только тире.

Comment: @Sharon да, действительно, абсурд получается. Запятыми выделяется та часть, которую можно изъять и переставить, а если в моём варианте изъять и переставить выделенную часть, остаток не сложится из-за тире во что-то внятное: *А я тебе говорю, что — я поеду с тобой, если ты поедешь*.

Comment: О да, ваши рассуждения совершенно справедливы,  о мудрейший (из речи джиннов) :))